# How to know that WebBrowser control has finished loading all content including flash?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

is there a way to know that the WebBrowser control has finished loading the page?
currently i am using WebBrowser.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete.
but this indicates that the webpage content is downloaded but sometimes the flash is not loaded yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well the best thing i have found is to use a timer to wait for a specifique time like 30 seconds and then the page should be loaded.
not perfect but the best i have thought of.

Answer (score 3):

A Flash file loading doesn't report its progress on that back to the browser so unfortunately you can't catch that.

Comment: Yup.  Same problem with Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over the Flash, you can put an ActionScript event that will then get passed to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

The `WebBrowser` control has a `DocumentCompleted` event which you can catch and react on. I don't know if that includes the Flash content loading - the docs aren't very clear on that....

```
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += 
     new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);

private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, 
                                     WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   // do whatever you need to do when the document is completely loaded here
}
```

Comment: but even so, it's easier and more efficient than constantly polling for `WebBrowser.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete.`

Comment: yeah but i am running several Webbrowsers on several worker threads, so the code got messy when i tried to implement events. so i left it like that. sure the cpu is @ 100% all the time but i need the task to get done. :)

Answer (score -1):

You can try this way:

```
bool loadingPage = true;

private void Browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
     if (this.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) return;
     if ((e.Url.AbsolutePath == "blank") || (e.Url != this.Url)) return;
     if (this.Document.Body.All.Count < 20) return;
     loadingPage = false
}

private void WaitPageLoad()
{
     //To avoid waiting forever. You can add timer here.
     while(loadingPage)
     {
     }
}
```